# get .key file from a .p12

Tags: ssl, openssl

I need to extract the .key from the .p12 container of a certificate, I have its password and I have tried to use openssl in windows, putting the .p12 in the bin folder, I run the windows console in administrator mode. I go to the location:
C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\openssl-1.0.2j-fips-x86_64\OpenSSL\bin

then i execute

openssl pkcs12 -in miarchivo.p12 -nocerts -out miclave.key

but it gives me the following error:

Error opening output file miclave.key
miclave.key: Permission denied

At no time has he asked me for the password he has or anything...

I need it to be able to install my .crt and .key certificate on my jitsi server...

Thank you.